# Can Sikuli observe changes in mouse pointer? (responsive vs non-responsive mouse)

Tags: javascript, python, jython, sikuli

I am controlling a Windows GUI with Sikuli (Sikuli 1.1.0 and Windows 7). The annoying thing is that the wizard *sometimes* needs ages to load the next stage of the wizard and at those instances my Sikuli script crashes because it does not wait for it. During these lag times I get the spinning windows circle as the mouse. Even worse, what also happens sometimes is that the "Next" button appears (the one I am waiting for with Sikuli) but the mouse is not ready yet to click it and is still in the spinning circle mode for an extra 20-30s. 
I do not want to specify 30s wait times at every stage in the wizard because that will unnecessarily and massively slow down the script execution; especially because most of the time I would not need it.

There was a similar issue reported here:
[How do I get sikuli to wait until the mouse pointer changes from "busy" to "not busy?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667507/how-do-i-get-sikuli-to-wait-until-the-mouse-pointer-changes-from-busy-to-not/36058135#36058135)

I was wondering whether there is some update about this issue? Can Sikuli recognize if the mouse is still in the spinning-circle non-responsive mode and would wait until the mouse is back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Sikuli supports this functionality, however you can work around this, in a way.

Use `exact` matches, then you'll have to loop until the field you are trying to type into has changed from a blank field to something with text in it(or whatever elements you are changing).  Once you have detected the change, you know things are no longer locked up.

But basically you'll be stuck looping and performing actions in the loop until you can detect that the actions you are trying to perform have stuck.

Here is a basic class you can use to handle this.

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, element, region):
        self.element = element
        self.region = region

    def stateChanged(self):
        if self.region.exists(Pattern(self.element).exact()):
            return False
        return True

gmailEmailField = Element("1458930208197.png", Region(438,239,388,342))

while not gmailEmailField.stateChanged():
    wait(.5)
```